# Any software recommendations for getting the metadata of a PDF?

Tags: pdf, sql, text-processing, text

I have 10,000 PDF files in my drive and I need to capture the following metadata. I tried using wordstat but I'm unable to capture the following:

1. File Name
2. File Type
3. Asset Type
4. Asset Title
5. Product Category
6. Product Type
7. Product Name
8. Publisher

Please see the sample below. This was done manually and I have 9,800 remaining PDF files.

[image]

Comment: It might be possible to write a program using [pikepdf](https://pypi.org/project/pikepdf/) or [QPDF](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/) to do what you want. Also, I recommend you add the `pdf` tag to your question.

Comment: Have you tried the Unix `pdfinfo` utility? You can use `pdfinfo -meta <pdf file>` to output PDF's metadata in XML. If you are on Windows, there might be alternatives to `pdfinfo`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19263643/windows-equivalent-for-unixs-pdfinfo

Comment: I tried `pdfinfo` and `exiftool` and the results have almost no overlap. I wonder why they are so different.

Answer (score 0):

[QuickPDF Library](https://www.debenu.com/blog/debenu-quick-pdf-library-11-15-released.html) from Foxit could do this, even the free Lite version.